# Computed Column as Average from Other Data in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a simple movie website that allows users to browse through movie titles, and rate movies with a 5 point rating system. I am using XAMPP, and phpAdmin to store my database through the SQL language. I have the following table below that stores ratings:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have the following table below that stores movies:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `movie_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `genre` text NOT NULL,
  `release_date` text NOT NULL,
  `price` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `movie_image` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to add a column, average_rating to my movies table that basically takes all rating values from movie_ratings from a specific movie_id and averages them and then stores the value into this new average_rating column within the movies table.

I believe I need a computed column, but I only know how to do this via columns from the same table, here I am using another table. I read that a view could be possible too... Would prefer to store the average rating in movies though as a new column.

So I created a VIEW but it's only displaying one movie and averaging.

```
CREATE VIEW movie_ratings_view AS 
    SELECT b.movie_id, b.movie_title, b.movie_image, b.price, AVG(br.rating) 
    AS avgRating FROM movies b INNER JOIN movie_ratings br ON 
    b.movie_id = br.movie_id;
```

Comment: What database is this for? "SQL" as a tag does not tell us enough. Appears to be MySQL. Have you considered using a "view" with the wanted calculation in it (and hence not trying to store it)?

Comment: @Used_By_Already yes this is MySQL, I've added the tag. And yes, I've considered creating a view, but figured I could store it too. But upon researching it looks like only a function can do this. So a view would be more suitable after all... I will try to create a view now and see if it ends up working and update the question.

Comment: @Used_By_Already See my question again now with a view added, could you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Please note I added an alternative query for consideration.

Comment: Thank you, the initial answer worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `group by` clause

```
CREATE VIEW movie_ratings_view
AS
SELECT
      b.movie_id
    , b.movie_title
    , b.movie_image
    , b.price
    , AVG(br.rating) AS avgRating
FROM movies b
INNER JOIN movie_ratings br ON b.movie_id = br.movie_id
GROUP BY
      b.movie_id
    , b.movie_title
    , b.movie_image
    , b.price
;
```

An alternative (if/when subqueries are allowed in the from clause of a view by MySQL):

```
CREATE VIEW movie_ratings_view
AS
SELECT
      m.movie_id
    , m.movie_title
    , m.movie_image
    , m.price
    , COALESCE(mr.numRatings, 0) AS numRatings
    , COALESCE(mr.avgRating, 0)  AS avgRating
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            movie_id
          , COUNT(rating) AS numRatings
          , AVG(rating)   AS avgRating
      FROM movie_ratings
      GROUP BY movie_id) mr ON m.movie_id = mr.movie_id
;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes... thanks.. a note added... a very annoying limitation

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient code for a view is a correlated subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW movie_ratings_view AS
    SELECT m.movie_id, m.movie_title, m.movie_image, m.price
           (SELECT AVG(mr.rating)
            FROM movie_ratings mr
            WHERE mr.movie_id = m.movie_id
           ) as avgRating
    FROM movies m;
```

This can make use of an index on `movie_ratings(movie_id, rating)`.  And it doesn't have the outer `GROUP BY` which can be expensive.

It is slightly different because this will return movies with no ratings -- but that might even be desirable.